# print imagemagick convert output to browser

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following code:

```
import subprocess
convertargs = ['convert', 'image1.tif', 'img2.tif', 'pdf:-']
print "Content-type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n"

pdf = subprocess.Popen(convertargs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pdf, error = pdf.communicate()

print pdf
```

It's supposed to take convertargs, use imagemagick's convert to convert the images into a pdf.

I know this works because when I run the following at the shell:

```
./pdf.py > test.pdf
```

it creates for me a neat little PDF with the correct images. It does not, however, work when I go to www.myhost.com/pdf.py. And I cannot figure out why. 
Here's what my apache error log says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
   File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py", line 59, in <module>: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
     pdf = subprocess.Popen(convertargs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE): /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
     errread, errwrite): /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
     raise child_exception: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pdf.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` can't find `convert`, probably because the webserver uses a different $PATH. Try feeding it the full path to `convert` instead of just `convert`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. Using the full path of convert fixed the problem.